# Enterprise service object from WSDL returns null

Tags: web-services, soap, abap

I created a service consumer through the wizard, based on a WSDL. Proxy object is generated, all structures and methods are found. Then, I add a logical port through SOAMANAGER - all fine, it pings and the connection works.

I populate the input structure, call my method and get an error: **Error during proxy processing (PART UNKNOWN (NULL))**. This is a very useless error message to me.

So, I activate all manners of tracing, so I can see what's going on calling and retrieving data. I can see that

1. My proxy is called correctly
2. The payload sent TO the service looks correct
3. The payload received FROM the service is correct. I know this because it's identical to the XML I get back calling the service through other means.
4. The transformation is empty

Here a screen of (the start of) the returned XML. `getRecordsResult` set is what I need:

[image]

This is the second response, after "conversion":

[image]

Nothing about this service has been customized: it's generated straight up through the wizard. I have already deleted and recreated it but no results.

Anyone got any advice on what to do next?

Comment: What version is your ABAP stack? Is there any change you can share the WSDL with us? There are limitations in the data types supported when generating proxies for WSDL files. See notes [944029](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/944029) and [1327511](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1327511) for more information.

Comment: We're on 7.40. I could share the WSDL but it's large, I'll see if I can add it somewhere.. it's for Service Now, in case you're familiar with it. I have a feeling the SimpleTransformation stuff is missing a node in the tree somewhere.

Comment: Yes, you could be right. You may need to tweak the WSDL a little to change the unsupported elements to ones that are supported. A little painful, I agree. I see ServiceNow also has a REST API, so you could also use that (albeit without the proxy generation).